# How to set private font in textbox telerik reporting

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, app-config, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am try to apply new font-family in telerik report , which are not install on system, this can be achieve like add private font in **app.config**

[image]

```
<Telerik.Reporting>
<privateFonts>
  <add fontFamily="Stratum1" path="~\Fonts\TGDQIK+Stratum1-Black.ttf" />      
</privateFonts>
</Telerik.Reporting>
```

But After that I am not able to understand or not able to fit how can I use or apply this font in textbox

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please refer below article which helps you

https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/configuring-telerik-reproting-privatefonts

Comment: this article only explain , how to configure & install fort file dynamically , It will not explain how to use in textbox

Comment: how can I dynamically apply that font in textbox at runtime